# Export files of a particular object

Tags: files, data-export

Is there any way to export all the files of a particular object in an org?

Comment: Hi. Do you mean "files" for the record data, or do you mean "files" as in "attachments" ([content documents](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)) related to those objects' records?

Comment: @PhilW Files as in attachments(content documents)

Comment: SOQL includes syntax for handling polymorphic lookup fields, allowing you to restrict the query to find records related to a specific object type through that polymorphic lookup field. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm). Use the [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) records with the appropriate `LinkedEntityId` and SOQL polymorphic syntax.